# Where does the fire daimyo live?

Tags: naruto

Konoha is a *hidden* village, and the Fire Daimyo is the ruler over the whole of fire country - so presumably, he has to live in a big city somewhere easily accessible, as he must constantly be, you know, ruling. And yet, Tora the cat, which belongs to the daimyo's wife, has escaped in konoha at least 7 times. So either she lives there, or visits very frequently. So where does the daimyo actually live? Does his wife live with him, or in konoha?